# How to import in Java with two classes with the same name

Tags: java

Now I'm having a bit of problem. I'm writing a converter functions and let's say I want to convert one type of card (one class) to another type (another class).

Let's say one is foo.bar.Card and the other is baz.banan.Card. I can have one

```
import foo.bar.Card;
```

but I can't do

```
import foo.bar.Card;
import baz.banan.Card;
```

as then the compiler can't tell them apart.

I could do just one of them and then prefix the other so I have Card and baz.banan.Card in my code, but I want to avoid having very long names. Ideally I would like to use bar.Card and banan.Card but is that possible and if so how?

Comment: the only way i could think of is wrapping one of them into a dummy class which is named different!

Comment: I think there is no way then. :(

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7193475/2773311) if you don't need to access `static` variables and functions you can extend one of them.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options:

1. Rename your classes to unique names
2. Refer to your class names using the fully qualified name:

   ```
   foo.bar.Card card = new foo.bar.Card();
   baz.banan.Card otherCard = new baz.banan.Card();
   ```

Another option, as whaleberg suggested, is to create a wrapper class with a different name.

Comment: He explicitely said he doesn't want to prefix the Objects to avoid having very long names

Comment: 1. Not an option in my case. 2. That is what I don't want to do.

Comment: Then there is no way to keep these classes apart. How should the compiler know that when you write `Card`, you mean package X and in the other case package Y if you don't provide the fully qualified name? Sometimes you want to avoid something but if the design doesn't allow it, your options are limited.

Comment: A third option would be to wrap one of the classes in a new class that delegates to the wrapped class.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately their isn't really a way to do this.

I do know of two somewhat useful workarounds:

**Final Class**

Create a wrapper class for one of the `Card` classes with the exact same methods that calls the `Card` objects methods. This isn't a very elegant approach unfortunately.

**Mutable Class**

Create a `CardA` class that extends `Card` and use `CardA` as your `Card` class.

Unfortunately these are you only two options. If these don't work you will have to use the fully qualified name.