# StringBuilder changing to java.lang.StringBuilder in Intellij in some projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stringbuilder

In most of my Intellij projects, when I type `StringBuilder` it remains just like that an I'm able to use the Class as normal. However, in certain projects when I type, it auto-completes to `java.lang.StringBuilder` which you can see on line 7. I'm assuming it's to do with my package structure or another quirk of Intellij that I haven't figured out yet.

[image]

It's not preventing me from working but it is making little sense to me when it doesn't behave this way in other projects.

Any advice welcome!

Comment: add `import java.lang.StringBuilder` on the top.

Comment: Tried that. I'll edit the original post to show you

Comment: In that case refer to the answer given by @Sam

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because there is already something named `StringBuilder` in the current context. In the case of the example you posted, your class itself is called `StringBuilder`. You can't refer to two different classes by the same name in a single file.

See also: [Importing two classes with same name. How to handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079823/importing-two-classes-with-same-name-how-to-handle?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: That worked. I knew I'd done something stupid. Thanks!