# Can't use both universal image loader and volley image loader inside application class

Tags: android

Below I have posted my application class.I have tried to add this below `universal image loader code` into `Appcontroller.java` class.

```
// UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);      ------> Compile error occurred here.because of imageloader import.

        // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
```

But I couldn't add this.Because In volley image loader import is different to that universal image loader.

***Imports:***

**Volley ImageLoader** - import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;

**Universal ImageLoader** -import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

If I add Universal Image Loader inside Appcontroller, I am getting compile error in this line `ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);`.

Because Two ImageLoader imports are differnet.

**AppController .java**:(Application Class)

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;

public class AppController extends Application {

    private static int pendingNotificationsCount = 0;

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    LruBitmapCache mLruBitmapCache;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        MultiDex.install(this);

        mInstance = this;




    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            getLruBitmapCache();
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, mLruBitmapCache);
        }

        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache getLruBitmapCache() {
        if (mLruBitmapCache == null)
            mLruBitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache();
        return this.mLruBitmapCache;
    }

    public void addToRequestQueue(Request<String> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        req.setShouldCache(false);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void addToRequestQueue(JsonObjectRequest req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }


    public static int getPendingNotificationsCount() {
        return pendingNotificationsCount;
    }

    public static void setPendingNotificationsCount(int pendingNotifications) {
        pendingNotificationsCount = pendingNotifications;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you? Why didn't you tell?

Comment: @greenapps edited the post.please check

Comment: `I am getting compile error` Any reason not to mention the exact error? You let us guess. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem doesn't come from using both UIL and Volley but using 2 classes with same name from different libraries.

You can use full qualified name like `com.package.path.ImageLoader` instead of `import` to solve the problem.

You also can check out this question: [Importing two classes with same name. How to handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079823/importing-two-classes-with-same-name-how-to-handle)

**Update with demo code**

Instead of

```
    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);      ------> Compile error occurred here.because of imageloader import.

    // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
```

Remove the `import` of either `ImageLoader`, and change the code to:

```
    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

            com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);      ------> Compile error occurred here.because of imageloader import.

    // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove imports and use `com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader`
and `com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader` instead of ImageLoader in code.