# Android How to set priorities for import class when 2 library have same package but different logic inside class in build.gradle

Tags: android, class, gradle, package

I'm using 2 libraries(A and B) and it have module with same package and class, but inside each class have different content.

I want to set import default is class of library A.

I don't know that how to set priorities for library A in build.gradle

Any solution would be appreciate!
Thank

Comment: maybe this link helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079823/importing-two-classes-with-same-name-how-to-handle

Comment: My library have same package, It's not only same class name

Comment: Don't use 2 libraries with the same package name and class names. Just use 1 library with 2 flavors

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti In my project, I need use 2 library to reduce price (2 library isnot open source)