# Classes in Same Package java applet

Tags: java, object, applet, package

I have `MixedComponent` class that extends `Applet`
And I have a `NumericTextField` class that i have made custom
Textfield by extending `TextField`.

Now,

I have both of these classes in Same Package `mypackage`.

Now I am making an object of `NumericTextField` in `MixedComponent`, and it
is giving me the error: *Cannot find symbol: NumericTextField*

```
NumericTextField myVar = new NumericTextField();
```

I want to use an object of type `NumericTextField` in MixedComponent 
How do i do that?

Comment: Obligatory "Applets are dead and modern browsers don't support them" comment.

Comment: Have you imported the `NumericTextField` class?

Comment: @Kayaman they are in same package so, i didn't import.

Comment: Well you have a compile time error. Check for typos and any other mistakes you've made.

Comment: No there isn't any typo error

Comment: Well are you compiling them correctly? How do you compile the files?

Comment: Since your custom classes are in the same package as the class where you want to use them and your custom classes have the same names as the applet classes you have to use the applet classes with their fully qualified names. Have a look at the question: [Importing two classes with same name. How to handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079823/importing-two-classes-with-same-name-how-to-handle)

Comment: @Kayaman  Compile -  javac ClassName.java

Comment: @LuCio both the classes have different name and are in same package

Comment: Have you compiled `NumericTextField` before trying to compile `MixedComponent`?

Comment: @Kayaman yess of course

Answer (score -1):

NumericTextField is in your package, but it's not directly visible. You will need to either import it or reference it using its containing class.

e.g.

```
import mypackage.MixedComponent.NumericTextField;

NumericTextField myVar = new NumericTextField();
```

or

```
MixedComponent.NumericTextField myVar = new MixedComponent.NumericTextField();
```

Comment: It is directly visible. It's in the same package. There's also no indication that `NumericTextField` is an inner class of `MixedComponent`, and if it were, the code would work just fine.